# can't set an external editor in mongo shell.(Mac OS)

Tags: mongodb

I want to set an external editor in mongo shell, but I get this error.

```
sh: /Applications/CodeRunner.app: is a directory
editor exited with error (32256), not applying changes
```

As the [mongodb doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-mongo-shell/#use-an-external-editor-in-the-mongo-shell) says, I did the following before starting mongo shell.

```
export EDITOR='/Applications/CodeRunner.app'
echo $EDITOR
/Applications/CodeRunner.app
open $EDITOR
```

I made sure that I can launch the editor 'CodeRunner' by running `echo $EDITOR`.

After this, I entered mongo shell and did the following but got the error.

```
var obj = {}
edit obj
sh: /Applications/CodeRunner.app: is a directory
editor exited with error (32256), not applying changes
```

Could please anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this error?

Comment: Unless you have any specific reason to use external editor. you can go for https://robomongo.org/ It gives you all feature which you can do in shell. with a overview of table

Answer (score 1):

The MacOS `.app` "file" that you see in the Finder is in fact an [application bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(macOS)#macOS_application_bundles) with a directory and file structure. You can peek under the covers by either listing the files in a Terminal session with `ls -laR /Applications/CodeRunner.app`, or by right-clicking on CodeRunner.app in Finder and choosing "View Package Contents" from the menu.

The actual executable can be found in the Contents/MacOS directory, so the correct setting for the EDITOR variable should be:

```
EDITOR="/Applications/CodeRunner.app/Contents/MacOS/CodeRunner"
```

However, I tested CodeRunner 2.3 with the MongoDB 3.6.3 shell and it doesn't work as expected as an editor for the `mongo` shell.

Setting the EDITOR variable and running `edit foo` in the `mongo` shell launches CodeRunner with a temporary file with the contents of `foo` (so far, so good). Unfortunately, saving this file or closing the tab in CodeRunner does not return control to the `mongo` shell. I found I have to quit the CodeRunner app in order to have edited results returned and resume my `mongo` shell session.

If your goal is to use a GUI editor for  JavaScript functions in the shell, one approach would be to save your JavaScript code in a file and use the [`load()` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load) to run this in the `mongo` shell after saving in your preferred editor. Alternatively you could look into MongoDB management tools with code editors (there are quite a few, open source and otherwise). [DbKoda](https://www.dbkoda.com/) is one such example which is cross-platform and open source.

If you need to work with data or query results but do not need any custom functions, I would recommend using a data management UI such as [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass).